# Where does command-line log when it crashes?

Tags: command-line, crash, log

In ubuntu bionic beaver (18.04) command-line I have been executing an application script (from a game, FTL, whatever) : I do `. ./FTL`.
Each time the console crashes immediately and it closes, without giving me any information.
I have been wandering in /var/log. But I can't find any log to get information on what happened.
Could someone tell me where to find relevant information about this kind of crash ?

Comment: Crash dumps are found in /var/crash/  ; so clues on crashes themselves are usually found there.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that your run the command as `. ./FTL` (in otherwords, `FTL` is "sourced"). When you do this, the contents of the FTL script are executed by the current bash instance. If the script executes an `exit` instructions, it makes the bash instance exit, and since the child process of the terminal exited, the terminal window closes.

If you want to keep that window open, either execute the `FTL` script as a plain command (that will be executed in a child process):

```
./FTL # instead of ". ./FTL"
```

or start a child bash process, so that when FTL exits, this child process exits and you are back to the instance that runs in the terminal:

```
bash       # starts a child bash process
export PS1="child-$PS1" # optional, change of prompt will show that you returned to the parent bash instance
. ./FTL    # FTL executed by the child bash process
```